# eloquent query on many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relationship on users and accounts. My actual database is old and doesn't use the standard naming conventions, but I'll try to standardise here to make it clearer.

I'm trying to find who else has access to the same accounts as the user. I already have a list of the user's accounts from a previous query, so this is the mysql query I need.

```
select distinct user_id
FROM account_user 
WHERE account_id IN (2,6,22)
```

The account_user table includes these lines relevant to the query above.

```
id     account_id   user_id
3      2            1
13     6            1
69     6            31
51     22           1
169    22           37
```

The result should be an array of [1, 31, 37].

I've got most of the way there in eloquent with the following:

```
Account::whereIn('acc_id', [2,6,22])->with('users:id')->select('acc_id')->get()
```

This query returns a list of all accounts with users in the following form in tinker:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6414
all: [
  App\Models\Account {#6435
    account_id: 2,
    users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6368
      all: [],
    },
  },
  App\Models\Account {#6531
    account_id: 6,
    users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6532
      all: [
        App\Models\User {#6527
          id: 31,
          #pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#6409
            account_id: 6,
            user_id: 31,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  App\Models\Account {#6515
    account_id: 22,
    users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6511
      all: [
        App\Models\User {#6529
          id: 1,
          #pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#6526
            account_id: 22,
            user_id: 1,
          },
        },
        App\Models\User {#6524
          id: 37,
          #pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#6486
            account_id: 22,
            user_id: 37,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
],
```

}

This seems good, but for some reason isn't returning ALL the users associated with these accounts. Specifically it's excluding the original user (user_id=1) for accounts 2 and 6, which isn't a problem, but it makes me question whether it will be reliable in all cases, and I'm still not sure how to dig the user id out of that object.

Creating a model for account_user seems to be a better option so I can use:

```
$friends = AccountUser::distinct()->whereIn('account_id', [2,6,22])->select('user_id')->get()
```

I'm still not convinced this is better than running the original query, though. Should I stick to the original query or is there a reason to use one of the options above, or something else?

Comment: If you can directly query the pivot table, either via an `AccountUser` Model, or via `DB::table('account_user')`, that will likely always be more performant than using Laravel's (Eloquent) relationship and queries, simply due to not having to execute any joins or subqueries. Also, if your original query is missing results that your subsequent query includes, that one is probably better. I can't quite visualize _what_ specifically is missing from your first query, if you wanted to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76359616/edit) and show your tables and data, that might help.

Comment: Good point. I've added the relevant parts of the table. User 1 is missing from accounts 2 and 6 in the pivot version. The model version gives the right result, but still not in a convenient format. It sounds like it's better just to use DB::select(original query);